# Looking for Hotel prices dataset

Tags: data-request

I am looking for a dataset of hotel prices, I am couldn't find any public dataset. Anyone to have an idea on where can I find these information ?

Comment: This question needs more information. Hotel prices are extremely volatile, they can change from day to day. How stable do you want them to be? What countries? A dataset in what format? Please [read this](http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Here you find a very good dataset on Expedia Hotels.
Among the others, you find  ID of the hotel and country in which the hotel is located, mean price per night, number of searches on Expedia for a given hotel, mean customer review score, location desirability score etc..

https://www.kaggle.com/c/expedia-personalized-sort

> Expedia has provided a dataset that includes shopping and purchase data as well as information on price competitiveness. The data are organized around a set of “search result impressions”, or the ordered list of hotels that the user sees after they search for a hotel on the Expedia website. In addition to impressions from the existing algorithm, the data contain impressions where the hotels were randomly sorted, to avoid the position bias of the existing algorithm. The user response is provided as a click on a hotel or/and a purchase of a hotel room.
>
> Appended to impressions are the following:
>
> 1) Hotel characteristics
>
> 2) Location attractiveness of hotels
>
> 3) User’s aggregate purchase history
>
> 4) Competitive OTA information

Comment: Please describe what's in that dataset. *a very good* does not say much.