# Is there a dataset/Statistics about Hotel?

Tags: data-request

Is there a dataset/Statistics about Hotel?

For example, How many companies that run hotel business? How many properties does AccorHotels have, how many properties does Aman Resorts have, etc? How many rooms are there in each property? min, max, average price etc.

This [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chained-brand_hotels) gives some hint although much more information may need a  crawler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start here:

- https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=hotel
- https://data.world/datasets/hotel
- https://www.kaggle.com/search?q=hotel

Also check out this question/answer: [Looking for Hotel prices dataset](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/9293/looking-for-hotel-prices-dataset)

Comment: wikidata.org might be an option as well, although not all hotels may be notable enough to be listed

Comment: You *might* be able to find a list of all hotels using openstreetmap.org

Comment: It seems that the [answer](https://www.kaggle.com/c/expedia-personalized-sort) in your last link does not give this kind of questions, how many properties does AccorHotels have, how many properties does Aman Resorts have, etc?

Comment: Like @BarryCarter suggested, you can lookup hotel locations (that have been mapped on OpenStreetMap) via a tool like [Overpass Turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/). Follow this link to search any map view for hotels: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/NSz

Comment: According to https://www.creditdonkey.com/hotel-industry-statistics.html there are about 700K hotels in the world, and, per https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/search?q=hotel#values OSM lists about 400K of these (which is remarkably complete for OSM). You can find other hotel-like entities (motels, hostels, etc) at https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/tourism#values